# Batch script to calculate remaining days

Tags: batch-file

In Windows Batch scripting,

I want to extract the date after "until:" and with the current date I want to calculate how many days remaining until the certificate expires.

```
Serial number: 1300000119b2de558ca060bb5e000000000119
Valid from: Mon Jun 14 20:17:27 EET 2021 until: Thu Jun 08 14:36:44 EET 2023
Certificate fingerprints:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spent couple of hours and search in internet, I've completed the script. I tested many scenarios it looks okay and enough to me. Thanks.

```
@ECHO OFF

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "until:" %1') do set var=%%a
set "var2=%var:*Until: =%"
set "certyear=%var2:*EET =%"
set "certstringmonth=%var2:~4,3%"
for %%G in ("Jan 1" "Feb 2" "Mar 3" "Apr 4" "May 5" "Jun 6" "Jul 7" "Aug 8" "Sep 9" "Oct 10" "Nov 11" "Dec 12") do for /F "tokens=1,2" %%H in (%%G) do if %certstringmonth% == %%H set "certmonth=%%I" & goto HaveMonth
:HaveMonth
set "certday=%var2:~8,2%"
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%I in ("%certday%") do set "certday=%%I"
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%F in ('
    wmic PATH Win32_LocalTime GET Day^,Month^,Year /FORMAT:TABLE
') do (
    for /F "tokens=1-3" %%L in ("%%F") do (
        set CurrDay=%%L
        set CurrMonth=%%M
        set CurrYear=%%N
    )
)
set CurrDay=%CurrDay:~-2%
set CurrMonth=%CurrMonth:~-2%

IF %certyear% GTR %CurrYear% (call:c1 "%certyear%" "%CurrYear%") ELSE (IF %certyear% LSS %CurrYear% (call:c0) ELSE (IF %certyear% == %CurrYear% ( IF %certmonth% GTR %Currmonth% (call:c4 "%certday%" "%certmonth%" "%certyear%" "%Currmonth%") ELSE ( IF %certmonth% LSS %Currmonth% (call:c0) ELSE ( IF %certmonth% == %Currmonth% ( IF %certday% GTR %Currday% (call:c5 "%certday%" "%certmonth%" "%certyear%" "%Currday%") ELSE (IF %certday% LEQ %Currday% (call:c0))))))))

:c0
    ECHO 0 days remaining... It is already expired %certday%/%certmonth%/%certyear%
    EXIT

:c1
    SET /A "difyear=%~1 - %~2"
    IF "%difyear%" GTR "1" (call:c2 "%difyear%" "%certday%" "%certmonth%" "%certyear%") ELSE (call:c3 "%certday%" "%certmonth%" "%certyear%" "%Currmonth%") 
    EXIT

:c2
    SET /A "days = %~1 * 365"
    ECHO %days% days remaining until %~2/%~3/%~4
    EXIT

:c3
    SET /A "remmonth = 12 - %~4"
    SET /A "difmonth = %remmonth% + %~2"
    SET /A "days = %difmonth% * 30"
    ECHO %days% days remaining until %~1/%~2/%~3
    EXIT

:c4
    SET /A "dif2month = %~3 - %~4"
    SET /A "days = %dif2month% * 30"
    ECHO %days% days remaining until %~1/%~2/%~3
    EXIT

:c5
    SET /A "days = %~1 - %~4"
    ECHO %days% days remaining until %~1/%~2/%~3
    EXIT
```